# Load Balancer sftp persistence when a server goes offline

Tags: load-balancing, sftp

Let's say we have the following scenario:
We have two identical *nix servers using a shared filesystem. We connect through SFTP (not FTPS) to one of them to upload a file to the shared filesystem, the server goes offline and we get redirected to the second system which is still available.

My question is, would there be any connection persistence or the user will have to relogin? I guess a relogin would be needed because the ssh sessions are not shared between the two systems...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Based on my readings on the Internet, the user have to relogin, because the session are not shared, as what you already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "get redirected". If it's something like a DNS failover, then the client will know that the connection has been dropped so persistence is not possible.

It is possible to build an advanced load-balancing service which will terminate the SFTP connection and share state with another load-balancer so that any single component failure will be transparent to the client. However this could be very expensive if you went with products like the F5 BigIP.

In summary, it is possible but it would be expensive and add significant complexity.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you provide me a little bit more information about your second statement? (building a load-balancing service etc)